# Setting number of Decimals for QgsPalLayerSettings object

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

How can I set the number of decimals for QgsPalLayerSettings object? I used the following code (from QGIS Python Programming Cookbook).e

```
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(shp)
label.enabled = True
label.fieldName='tmp_Averag'
label.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.AroundPoint
label.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','')
#label.decimals = 2
label.writeToLayer(shp)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([shp])
```

I tried to read the API document and I thought

```
label.decimals = 2
```

does the job. But it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, `label.decimals` is the way to go. You are just missing the

```
label.formatNumbers = True
```

instruction, to make `QgsPalLayerSettings` format numbers.